# "A qualified teacher" vs. "A credentialed teacher"

Tags: expressions, synonyms

What's the clear-cut difference between "A qualified teacher" and "A credentialed teacher"?

Comment: The Atlantic Ocean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Qualified* means qualified: somebody (maybe the person speaking) thinks the teacher is qualified: capable of teaching adequately.

*Credentialed* means that the teacher has received some kind of credential: presumably a document from official or recognized organization that professes that the teacher has satisfied some criteria to become credentialed.  I'm being vague because the meaning of "credentialed" no doubt depends on where you are and what organizations there issue teaching credentials.

In some areas, teaching credentials have the authority of the state, indicating that the teacher has satisfied criteria set forth and tested by the state.

Beyond this vague description, you would need to be more precise about your context. And in that case the question would no doubt not be a question about English but a question about teaching credentials in your area (e.g. a question about law).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is no clear-cut difference.  Some states in the USA have laws for *teacher qualification*, some for *teacher certification*, and others for *credentials for teachers.*

*Credential*, related to *credence* and *credible* concerns something worthy of belief, that is, something reliable. A credential may be a written document stating that the teacher has the minimum education and skill to teach a particular topic. It could be a copy of the teacher's academic degree. It could be the state's license.

*Teacher qualification* and *teacher certification* often have the element of a background check for criminal history and written character references.

I was fortunate to have an *uncredentialed, uncertified* teacher for my high-school biology class. She was not *qualified*, she was *over-qualified*:  She was a PhD geneticist from the famous Johns Hopkins University in Baltimore. She was not educated as a teacher, she was educated in the subject matter.

Comment: Terminology! But these confusing differences can prove useful: would Sherlock have found the culprit in 'The Baskerville HOUND' if he'd been careful enough to say 'mobile' instead of 'cell phone'?

Answer (score 1):

*Qualified* is an adjective describing the persons suitability for a role in tems of having the desired qualities, and *credential* is a noun referring to the certificates, qualities, experience, etc. that show the person is qualified for the job.

In short, if you are qualified teacher you will usually have to prove it by providing credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Qualified mainly signifies the extrinsic value added to a person from a long term achievements in education and career. While Credential would rather denote the intrinsic value of a person with the achievements attained with talent and self motivation.